# Calculate total bill and Subtotals

Tags: java

Write a program that reads the total number of pieces of oranges, eggs, apples, watermelons, and bagels they purchased. Calculate the total bill and subtotals for each item using the following prices:

```
a.Oranges: 10 for 2.99/0.50 each 
b.Eggs: 12 for 1.69/0.25 each
c.Apples: 3 for 1.00/0.75 each
d.Watermelons: 4.39 each
e.Bagels: 6 for 3.50/0.95 each
```

I'm a little bit confused for on what method should I use to program/solve this problem? I'm thinking to use a `If` statement but I think it's not a good idea. How should i start my coding? This is my first time encountering a price system with (I think discount?) fix amount of price on each item. It's bothering me to think that how can i do a "`2.99 for 10 apples`" while one apple is `0.50?`" should I use discount? My mind is bleeding right now -_-

Comment: Break the problem in small parts and try implementing each part one by one.

Comment: Do some java tutorials. Try something, once you have some code but it does not work ask a question and add your code

Comment: What @PrerakSola says: break the problem into small parts. For example, how would you do it without discount?

Comment: The usual supermarket hype: buy more, pay less. But I'd go back to the source and ask how much the fourth apple is. 0.75 or 0.3333...? I know stores of both kind.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm for solving the problem. Go step by step and implement the logic. I am sure you will get the final result.

1. Take the count for one fruit and display it.
2. From the count, calculate the sub-total price by taking the rate as per piece. Display the sub-total.
3. Store the sub-total you got in 2nd step in a separate variable and display it.
4. Follow the steps 1 to 3 for other fruits now, storing the sub-total of each fruit in a separate variable.
5. Calculate the final total by adding the values of all sub-total variables.
6. For applying the discounts, you can use a simple `if...else` logic along with some arithmetic operators.

   6.1 Divide the count by 10 (for oranges) and store it in a variable called tmp.

   6.2 If tmp is greater than 0,

   - subTotal = tmp * price_of_10
   - count = count - (tmp * 10)
   - subTotal = subTotal + (count * price_of_1)

   6.3 If tmp is equal to zero

   - subTotal = count * price_of_1

Answer (score 0):

I can help you get started. I don't want to give you all the code because I still want you to learn from it.

```
 //Read number of Oranges here 
 //Some code
 if(number = 10) price = 2.99
 else price = number*0.50
 total += price
```

Repeat for other products, don't forget to change the price value

EDIT: if you want to buy more than 10 and still get the discount, you will need to do something like this

```
int ten = 0;
Double rest =0;

if(number/10 >= 1){
   ten = number/10;
   rest = number%10;
   price = ten*2.99 + rest*0.50;
}else{
   price = number*0.50
     }     
total += price
```

Comment: What about buying 10 for 2.99 and then coming back to buy an 11th for 0.50 (2.49) rather than buying 11 for 5.50? Ahem...